# How to call the angular4 function from the SSRS(Microsoft) Report?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

`enter code here`Please help.

I want to pass the id parameter from ssrs report to angular4 function, below is the SSRS Code.
I used the HostListener but its not working, not able to call the function of Angular.

getting  the below error when i click in the Id parameter of the SSRS report.

**The frame attempting navigation must be same-origin with the target if navigating to a javascript: url**

SSRS Code :- HTMl Console View

```
<div style="word-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-word;white-space:pre-wrap;" class="Afc3757ffa89a445aa85638e090ce625e37 canGrowTextBoxInTablix cannotShrinkTextBoxInTablix"><a tabindex="1" href="javascript:void(fetchProviderId('21866'))" style="" class="Afc3757ffa89a445aa85638e090ce625e37a" target="_top"><div style="width:41.25mm;min-width: 41.25mm;">21866</div></a></div>
```

Angular Function

```
fetchProviderId(value) {
alert(value)
}
```

Comment: btw, it is semantically better to use the click event to run the javascript command. `href` is for navigation. if click on `a` does not do the navigation, it is the `button`, not `a`

Answer (score 0):

It's not like I'm SRSS expert. I can provide you a generic method to communicate between the Angular and external app. You need to use some intermediate object which is accessible by both ANgular and SRSS. If you run this app in the browser, you can use `window` object. So, the Angular component or service will contain code like this:

```
window.fetchProviderId = this.fetchProviderId;
```

this way `fetchProviderId` will be accessible globally and the `href` handler would work.

Comment: hi @IAfanasov  first of all thanks, but where we need to write below line given my you window.fetchProviderId = this.fetchProviderId; because window.fetchProviderId giving me error.

Comment: that is not that simple question to answer (: it could be in a constructor of the component/service which declares `fetchProviderId` method. depending on the project structure I can imaging it in a lot of legitimate places

Comment: SSRS dont have window object. is there any way around?

Comment: the `window` is an object inside the browsers. if your app is running on a server and not in the browser,  you can use `process` global objecct